# ConnectyCube Retrieving list of dialog returns an empty list

Tags: java, android, connectycube

I'm trying to implement the connecty cube API in my app when using the following code the dialogs `ArrayList` is empty. How can I retrieve all the chat dialogs?

This method is giving me an empty list:

```java
@Override
public void onSuccess(ArrayList<ConnectycubeChatDialog> dialogs, Bundle params) {
    int totalEntries = params.getInt(Consts.TOTAL_ENTRIES);
}
```

complete method code:

```java
RequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestGetBuilder();
requestBuilder.setLimit(50);
requestBuilder.setSkip(100);
//requestBuilder.sortAsc(Consts.DIALOG_LAST_MESSAGE_DATE_SENT_FIELD_NAME);

ConnectycubeRestChatService.getChatDialogs((ConnectycubeDialogType) null, requestBuilder).performAsync(new EntityCallback<ArrayList<ConnectycubeChatDialog>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<ConnectycubeChatDialog> dialogs, Bundle params) {
        int totalEntries = params.getInt(Consts.TOTAL_ENTRIES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ResponseException exception) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put a code that we can execute and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
requestBuilder.setSkip(100);
```

means you want skip 100 items and than select 50. Are you sure you have more than 100 dialogs?

As example you can use theirs [sample app](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/android-messenger-app).

[Here](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/android-messenger-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/connectycube/messenger/api/ConnectycubeService.kt#L92) code to load dialogs.

Comment: Thank you! 
Worked like a charm